# What happens technically when a file is required in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I have a file called `app.rb` that requires another file called `foo.rb`, what does Ruby do under the hood to make the constants defined in `foo.rb` become available in `app.rb`?

From "The Ruby Programming Language" by Yukihiro Matsumoto:

> Files loaded with load or require are executed in a new top-level scope that is different
>   from the one in which load or require was invoked. The loaded file can see all global
>   variables and constants that have been defined at the time it is loaded, but it does not
>   have access to the local scope from which the load was initiated.

I'm having a hard time visualizing this.

---

For example:

**foo.rb**:

```
class Foo
  def hello
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

**app.rb**:

```
require_relative "foo"

foo_obj = Foo.new
foo_obj.hello # => "Hello, world!"

p Object.constants.grep /^Foo/ # => [:Foo]
```

What does Ruby do to add the `Foo` constant into the `Object` class?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Are you asking about how constants work or how `require` works?

Comment: When a file is required, all the constants from that file (classes, modules, and regular constants) are added to the Object class in the current file. I am trying to understand what `require` does to make this possible.

Comment: Nothing. It just runs the file. The top-level is special: methods defined at the top-level become `private` instance methods of `Object`, constants defined at the top-level become constants of `Object`, instance variables defined at the top-level become instance variables of the `main` top-level object. But that has absolutely nothing to do with `require`.

Comment: And the constants from a required file also become top-level constants of Object, correct?

Comment: That depends on how they are defined. Let me repeat again: `require` just runs the file. Period. There is absolutely nothing special whatsoever going on, not with constants nor with any other thing. The code is just ran the exact same way as any other Ruby code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, quite directly, it looks up the path given as an argument to `require` in all the directories in the current $LOAD_PATH.  If it finds a file with that partial path in one of the base paths in $LOAD_PATH, then it loads it. It also marks it as loaded -- require will never load the same file twice, if you require the same file twice the second time is basically a no-op.

With regard to the local scope, it's pretty straightforward:

```
 foo = "x"
 require 'some_file'
```

The some_file required there (whether loaded with `require` or `load`) does not have access to that local variable 'foo'.  It is *not* just as if the code were pasted in at the point it's load/require'd.  Instead it's loaded into it's own local scope, sharing no local variables with the context that loaded/required it.

Similarly, local variables set inside the required `some_file` are not visible outside it either, after the require. Again, it is *not* just as if the code had been pasted in at that point. The code is loaded, but it does not share any local variable access with the context at the point it was loaded/required.

You may or may not have expected it to. That's it, that's all it means.

But that just applies to local variables. Constants defined outside the required some_file are still available to it; and constants defined inside the required some_file are still available to other things after it's been loaded.  Recall that ruby classes are actually accessed via constants (SomeClass is a constant, that points to the actual class). So this is why constants defined in some_file are available to any other code, after it's been require'd or load'ed.

I'm not sure how to answer "what it does to make that possible", beyond looking through the C implementation (which is beyond me too). It just... loads the file into the current ruby environment. That's what makes it possible. But it loads it as if it were in it's own scope for local variables, which is why it doesn't share local variables.

Comment: If the required file and the current file are executed in different scopes, how are the constants defined in the required file accessible without the need to use the namespace resolution operator? Is it because all outer level constants are defined in the Object class?

Comment: That concept of 'scope' only applies to local variables. Constants are global and are always in scope for everything. If you used namespace resolution operator, what namespace would you use? Namespaces are a different thing, and you CAN define constants in a namespace (or not), but either way they are accessible from any scope.  I am not sure if technically constants are defined in the Object class or not, good question. But constants are available in all scopes. The concept of 'scope' really only applies to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the underlying C code that Ruby uses to require a file

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/load.c#L959

```
int
rb_require_internal(VALUE fname, int safe)
{
    volatile int result = -1;
    rb_thread_t *th = GET_THREAD();
    volatile VALUE errinfo = th->errinfo;
    int state;
    struct {
    int safe;
    } volatile saved;
    char *volatile ftptr = 0;

    if (RUBY_DTRACE_REQUIRE_ENTRY_ENABLED()) {
    RUBY_DTRACE_REQUIRE_ENTRY(StringValuePtr(fname),
                  rb_sourcefile(),
                  rb_sourceline());
    }

    TH_PUSH_TAG(th);
    saved.safe = rb_safe_level();
    if ((state = EXEC_TAG()) == 0) {
    VALUE path;
    long handle;
    int found;

    rb_set_safe_level_force(safe);
    FilePathValue(fname);
    rb_set_safe_level_force(0);

    if (RUBY_DTRACE_FIND_REQUIRE_ENTRY_ENABLED()) {
        RUBY_DTRACE_FIND_REQUIRE_ENTRY(StringValuePtr(fname),
                       rb_sourcefile(),
                       rb_sourceline());
    }

    path = rb_str_encode_ospath(fname);
    found = search_required(path, &path, safe);

    if (RUBY_DTRACE_FIND_REQUIRE_RETURN_ENABLED()) {
        RUBY_DTRACE_FIND_REQUIRE_RETURN(StringValuePtr(fname),
                        rb_sourcefile(),
                        rb_sourceline());
    }
    if (found) {
        if (!path || !(ftptr = load_lock(RSTRING_PTR(path)))) {
        result = 0;
        }
        else if (!*ftptr) {
        rb_provide_feature(path);
        result = TAG_RETURN;
        }
        else {
        switch (found) {
          case 'r':
            state = rb_load_internal0(th, path, 0);
            break;

          case 's':
            handle = (long)rb_vm_call_cfunc(rb_vm_top_self(), load_ext,
                            path, 0, path);
            rb_ary_push(ruby_dln_librefs, LONG2NUM(handle));
            break;
        }
        if (!state) {
            rb_provide_feature(path);
            result = TAG_RETURN;
        }
        }
    }
    }
    TH_POP_TAG();
    load_unlock(ftptr, !state);

    rb_set_safe_level_force(saved.safe);
    if (state) {
    /* never TAG_RETURN */
    return state;
    }

    th->errinfo = errinfo;

    if (RUBY_DTRACE_REQUIRE_RETURN_ENABLED()) {
    RUBY_DTRACE_REQUIRE_RETURN(StringValuePtr(fname),
                  rb_sourcefile(),
                  rb_sourceline());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know C otherwise I would've read the source code myself. Can you explain in simple terms what happens when a file is required?

Answer (score -2):

Creates a new `Foo` object, with all his methods. With `foo_obj.hello` you're calling the method `hello` from the class `Foo`.

Do you now something about OOP?

Comment: The question is not about instantiating a `Foo`, but about adding `Foo` itself as a constant. It's _how does `require` work_, not _how does `new` work_.